# Detect rows in DataGridView whose cell values have been changed by user

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a VB.NET WinForms project that I'm building in VS2013. In a DataGridView bound to a DataSet I want to highlight each row that the user has changed - and if the user changes a row's contents back to its original values (as compared to the database values) I want to remove the highlighting.

I have been Googling for a while now and really haven't gotten anywhere.

All I know at this point is that `EmployeesDataSet.HasChanges(DataRowState.Modified)` returns False in the CellValueChanged event after having changed text in a cell and clicked out of the row.

My assumption is that the overall method would be something like on KeyUp event compare the current row's cell values to the DataSet (or BindingSource or TableAdapter?) and if anything is different, highlight the row, otherwise set the row to the default backcolor.

But if that's the right approach I don't understand what I would compare the row's contents to. Would it be the DataSet? The TableAdapter? The BindingSource? If it's one of those, how to I compare the correct row?

**UPDATE**

Some more research has made some progress:

I found this iteration code:

```
Dim dsChanged As DataSet = EmployeesDataSet.GetChanges()

For Each dt As DataTable In dsChanged.Tables
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            Dim currentBackColor As System.Drawing.Color = dgvEmployees.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor
            If Not row(i, DataRowVersion.Current).Equals(row(i, DataRowVersion.Original)) Then
                dgvEmployees.Rows(dt.Rows.IndexOf(row)).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink
            Else
                ' No changes so set it to its original color
                dgvEmployees.Rows(dt.Rows.IndexOf(row)).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = currentBackColor
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
```

I put this in a separate Sub, which is being called in the DataGridView.CellValueChanged event.

That correctly detects the rows that have changed cell values, but my code to color the background isn't quite right. As is, it is coloring each successive row from top to bottom as I make changes - regardless of what row in the DGV I edit.

I assumed that dt.Rows.IndexOf(row) would correctly get the correct index of the DGV, since I'm iterating through the DGV's DataTable.

Comment: On load of the form, I would create a list of the unmodified data from your bound DataGridView (data in your dataset). When a user modifies the DataGridView, you will be able to compare your initial list of data to the current data in the DataGridView. Enabling you to decide whether or not to change the row color or tell the user there's a modified entry in the grid view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you go hunting long enough and spend enough time trying different things, you'll eventually find an answer...

Here's the working code I ended up with:

```
Private Sub dgvEmployees_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvEmployees.CellValueChanged
    ' Pass the row and cell indexes to the method so we can change the color of the correct row
    CompareDgvToDataSource(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub CompareDgvToDataSource(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, ByVal columnIndex As Integer)

    If Not dgvEmployees Is Nothing And dgvEmployees.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        ' Condition required because this Method is also called when the DGV is being built and populated
        Console.WriteLine("rowIndex: " & rowIndex.ToString() & ", columnIndex: " & columnIndex.ToString() & ", cell value: " & dgvEmployees.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Value.ToString())
    End If

    ' Force ending Edit mode so the last edited value is committed
    EmployeesBindingSource.EndEdit()

    Dim dsChanged As DataSet = EmployeesDataSet.GetChanges()

    If Not dsChanged Is Nothing Then

        For Each dt As DataTable In dsChanged.Tables
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                    If Not row(i, DataRowVersion.Current).Equals(row(i, DataRowVersion.Original)) Then
                        Console.WriteLine("Row index: " & dt.Rows.IndexOf(row))
                        dgvEmployees.Rows(rowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightPink
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

*A couple of notes:*

Without calling EndEdit() on the BindingSource the changes won't be detected since this is being called by the CellValueChanged, which happens **before** the BindingSource is changed.

I tried adding an Else clause to set the BackColor to the original color (for when the DGV row is detected to be the same as the DataSet's row or when validation fails), but I can't figure out how to account for the DGV.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor property being set. Ideas???

I think this could be improved by, since I have the row and column indexes in the Method, just going directly to the DataSet's/DataTable's corresponding row and comparing just that, instead of iterating through the entire DataSet. Ideas on that one would be appreciated, but I'll do some more testing to see if I can get it (I figured it out myself this far...)